# Jquery MagicLine - issue when header is sticky

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have wordpress website, with blog post filtering on home page.
When you click on one of the filters - the posts changing by the category of the chosen filter.

What i am trying to do - is to add "MagicLine" like posted on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6bewcyz/39/) , with one different - i need the Magic Line will do the transition **on click** and not **on hover**.

I also succeed with that one.

**1st Issue**

Now, i have issue that i can't over.The "filter bar" is sticky... when you scroll the page - the filter bar is get sticky.... **The issue: on scrolling - the magic line is losing it position**.I tried so many things like document scroll and set new positions - but... still - nothing.

**2nd Issue**

Sometimes, when you click fast between the filter links - the filter is "stuck".. its not working - the posts not replacing, and actually the filter jquery functions not running. it happen only when the Magic Line function is enabled.

```
/* 
* Filters transitations effect 
* ====================
*/
jQuery(".ee-filters").append('<span id="slide-line"></span>');
var j$ = jQuery,

$nav = j$("ul.ee-filters"),
// $navLi = j$(".filterTitle"),
$slideLine = j$("#slide-line"),
$currentItem = j$(".ee--active");


j$(function(){  
  // Menu has active item
  if ($currentItem[0]) {
    //j$($slideLine).text(j$($currentItem).text()),
    $slideLine.css({
        "width": $currentItem.width() + 30,
        "left": $currentItem.position().left - 18,
        "top": ($currentItem).position().top,
    });

  }

  // Underline transition
  j$('ul.ee-filters li').click(

    // Hover on
    function(){

        //j$($slideLine).text(j$(this).text()).fadeIn('9000'),
        $slideLine.css({
            "width": j$(this).width(),
            "left": j$(this).position().left + 23,
            "top": j$(this).position().top + 39,
        });

    }

    );
});
/* END OF FILTERS UNDERLINE TRANSITATIONS EFFECT */

jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 60) {
    // user scrolled 60 pixels or more;
    if ($currentItem[0]) {
            $slideLine.css({
                "width": $currentItem.width() + 30,
                "left": $currentItem.position().left - 15,
                "top": $currentItem.position().top + 39,
            });

    }

} 
});
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<ul class="ee-filters ee-filters--category sticky">
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item">
<a class="ee--active" data-filter="*">
<span data-filter="*" class="filterTitle ee--active">All posts</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--culture">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-1" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-1" class="filterTitle">Culture</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--kids">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-2" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-2" class="filterTitle">Kids</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--events">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-3" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-3" class="filterTitle">Events</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--enclosures">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-4" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-4" class="filterTitle">Places</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--tours-and-sports">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-6" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-6" class="filterTitle">Sports</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--culinary">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-7" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-7" class="filterTitle">Food</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="ee-filters__item o-nav__item ee-term ee-term--parks-and-nature">
<a data-filter=".ee-filter-8" class="ee-term__link">
<span data-filter=".ee-filter-8" class="filterTitle">Parks</span>
</a>
</li>
<span id="slide-line" style="width: 102px; left: 835.953px; top: 40px;"></span></ul>
```

Comment: You don't want the bar to be sticky at all?

Comment: I want the bar to be sticky, but take a look the issue with the "magic line" under the filter anchors... it loosing it place when scrolling the page.

Comment: The reason is cause you put `left: xx` on the bar which is not 100% but when you stick it you give it a new width of 100% so the left is resting based on his parent which is now 100% wide

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz - thanks. i added image on the question that explain the issue, i am not sure if you solution speaking about this issue.

Comment: My solution is for your issue, let's say your container is 900px, and you click on a link, the blue background gets a `left: 100px` so its 100px from the left, when you scroll you give a `width:100%` so `left:100px` isnt the right number anymore, it should be 100px plus the new width added now to the parent

Comment: @MoisheySchwartz thanks again. so this solution must be through the document scroll event, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178881/discussion-between-moishey-schwartz-and-oshrib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Container Is being resized on scroll but your `span` with the blue Background is not updating position.

Let's say your container is 900px, and you click on a link, the blue background gets a `left: 100px` so its 100px from the left, when you scroll you give a `width:100%` so `left:100px` isn't the right number anymore, it should be 100px plus the new width added now to the parent, Or you can just add the nav items and the span in a separate container that won't change and just change his parents width.